# Serial Port will only receive DataReceived when in break status

Tags: c#, serial-port, rfid

I am using a serial port to receive data from an RFID reader. it will recieve and display the dta the first time it is send, but will not after that...EXCEPT when I put a break point on the DataReceived event. Then, it works every time. Hits the break point and upon F5, displays it fine. Tried timers and all kinds of stuff, but have yet to get it working reliably (outside having a break point). I do not understand why and how to fix this.
Here is the class code I am using, its not the neatest anymore since i have been mucking about in it:

```
public class RFIDReader
{
    private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort _scannerPort;

    private Control _control;
    private string _port;
    private int _baud;
    private string _pariStr;
    private int _dataBits;
    private int _stopBits;
    private string _suffix;

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the specified Serial Scanner.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tagCheck">The beginning character to verify against, and the control to place value in</param>
    public void Start(Control tagCheck)
    {
        _control = tagCheck;

        GetScannerSettings();
        try
        {
            _scannerPort.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
            _scannerPort.DtrEnable = true;
            _scannerPort.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception _e)
        {
            MessageWindow.Show("Scanner Setting Error", _e.Message, MessageWindow.ButtonStyle.Ok,
                MessageWindow.IconStyle.Error);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        try
        {
            _scannerPort.Close();
            _scannerPort.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void GetScannerSettings()
    {
        string port = MySettings.get_Item("RFIDPort");
        string[] _sArr = MySettings.get_Item("RFIDSettings").Split(',');
        int _baud = Convert.ToInt32(_sArr[0]);
        string _pariStr = _sArr[1];
        int _dataBits = Convert.ToInt16(_sArr[2]);
        int _stopBits = Convert.ToInt16(_sArr[3]);
        string suffix = _sArr[4];
        Parity _pariSetting = ParseParity(_pariStr);
        StopBits _stopBitsSetting = ParseStopBits(_stopBits);
        _scannerPort = new SerialPort(MySettings.get_Item("RFIDPort"))
        {
            BaudRate = _baud,
            DataBits = _dataBits,
            StopBits = _stopBitsSetting,
            Parity = _pariSetting
        };
    }

    private StopBits ParseStopBits(int stopBits)
    {
        StopBits _stopBitsSetting;
        switch (stopBits)
        {
            case 0:
                _stopBitsSetting = StopBits.None;
                break;
            case 1:
                _stopBitsSetting = StopBits.One;
                break;
            case 2:
                _stopBitsSetting = StopBits.Two;
                break;
            default:
                _stopBitsSetting = StopBits.One;
                break;
        }
        return _stopBitsSetting;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Parses the parity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pariStr">The pari string.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Parity ParseParity(string pariStr)
    {
        Parity _pariSetting;
        switch (pariStr)
        {
            case "e":
                _pariSetting = Parity.Even;
                break;
            case "m":
                _pariSetting = Parity.Mark;
                break;
            case "n":
                _pariSetting = Parity.None;
                break;
            case "o":
                _pariSetting = Parity.Odd;
                break;
            case "s":
                _pariSetting = Parity.Space;
                break;
            default:
                _pariSetting = Parity.None;
                break;
        }
        return _pariSetting;
    }

    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string _b = ((SerialPort)sender).ReadExisting();
        if (_b.Contains("\n"))
        {
            _b = _b.Remove(_b.IndexOf("\n", StringComparison.Ordinal));
        }
        if (_b.Contains("\r"))
        {
            _b = _b.Remove(_b.IndexOf("\r", StringComparison.Ordinal));
        }
        SetTextCallback t = SetText;

        _control.Invoke(t, _b, _control);
        _control.Invoke(CallEmulateEnter);

    }

    private void SetText(string text, Control control)
    {
        control.Text = text;
    }

    private delegate void SetTextCallback(string text, Control control);
    public Func<bool> CallEmulateEnter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem when I had to implement gRPC server. When I had breakpoints it worked fine. The problem was deadlock.

Comment: You do know that `DataReceived` arrives on a different thread, correct?  And if it happens again before the first call is done processing data, you can have multiple `DataReceived` events being simultaneously processed.  It's not pretty.

Comment: Try using `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`.  It's as the others have suggested, the invoke is blocking.